# How can I find how much time is being spent in the SQLite engine on Android?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, profiling

We are trying to track down a performance issue in our app when we do a batch of database updates.  Using the Android DDMS Profiler in Eclipse seems to only show the amount of CPU time spent in the java code, it appears to not include the time spent in the SQLite engine.
This makes it VERY hard to determine where all the wall-clock time is being spent.

Is there any way to find out how much wall-time is being spent in the various SQLite engine calls?

Comment: You mention that it's a batch of updates.  Are you wrapping this batch in a transaction?  If you are, can't you just log the system time before and after you begin/end the transaction?  If you're not using a transaction, sounds like you'll see huge gains if you refactor it into a transaction.

Comment: Yes, we are using transactions.  I already know that it takes a long time for the whole transaction.  I'd like to find out just what parts I'm spending a lot of time doing, as maybe I can change things so that we don't do that.
It's a large complex schema, with large complex updates.

Answer (score 0):

Android's SQLite wrappers do not expose helper functions such as the [progress callback](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/progress_handler.html); the best you can do is to manually wrap all the engine calls in your app with timestamping functions.

Comment: Bleh.  I was worried we'd have to do something stupid like that.
I'd already made some guesses at which methods were causing the delays, and found the problem.  (We had a block of code deleting a large number of records individually, rather than as a single sql statement.)